# How to avoid enemies overlapping each other when chasing player in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, ai

I am trying to get enemies to chase player but without them overlapping each other when they get closer to the player.

So far what I have is that I check for the distance between current enemy and the another enemy in a list and if their distance is less than 2 then update their position away from each other.

But when I do that, the enemies instantly move away rather than smoothly moving away from each other. What can I do to improve this?

Here is my script for chasing player:

```
public void ChasePlayer()
{
    foreach (GameObject enemy in enemies)
    {
        if (enemy != null)
        {
            float currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position);

            if (currentDistance < 2.0f)
            {
                Vector3 dist = transform.position - enemy.transform.position;
                transform.position += dist;
            }
        }
    }

    if (lantern.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Light>().enabled)
    {

        gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
        gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = true;
        transform.LookAt(player.transform);
        transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    }
    else
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
        gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your approach, and look into using the Unity's NavMesh Agent system instead.

With a `nevmeshagent`, there is a property on the agent which offsets the character along a vertical axis to get a result you would be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. All I needed to do was multiply `dist` by `Time.deltatime`.

Like so: `transform.position += dist * Time.deltatime;`